# Return case of in a do block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

So I'm new to Haskell and probably asking a really silly question.
I try to get the following code to run:

```
asdf :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
asdf k = do
    return $ case k of 
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just x -> Just x
```

I know that this is basically `fmap` and that the do only with a return is non sense. What I actually want to do is the following

```
vote :: PostId -> Bool -> Maybe (Int, Int)
vote id v = do
  p <- runSQL $ P.get id
  return $ case p of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just p -> do
                let uv = postUpvotes p
                let dv = postDownvotes p
                let nuv = if v then uv + 1 else uv
                let ndv = if not v then dv + 1 else dv
                runSQL $ update id [PostUpvotes =. nuv, PostDownvotes =. ndv]
                (nuv, ndv)
```

I guess this has more than one issue to it. What exactly is wrong with my first example? Is the approach to the second problem entirely wrong or what's up with that? How would you write it?

Comment: What's the type of `runSQL`? I assume it's not pure so you can't run it within a function returning a `Maybe (Int, Int)`.

Comment: It's from this tutorial: https://www.spock.li/tutorials/rest-api

Comment: You can't do IO unless you return a value in the `IO` monad, possibly something like `IO (Maybe (Int, Int))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code sample does not need the `return`.

Have you figured out what `return` means in Haskell? It is not like `return` in any other programming language. In most languages its a flow of control statement that returns control to the calling function with a value attached. In Haskell its just a function with a misleading name.

In this case you should say:

```
asdf k =
    case k of 
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just x -> Just x
```

In Haskell `do` notation is used with monads, like IO. Confusing the matter here is the fact that `Maybe` is actually a monad as well. In fact its the simplest monad there is. You only need to use monads when you want a daisy chain of functions that run in some kind of context, which isn't the case here.

Moving on to your second example, the problem is that `runSQL` has to interact with the outside world, so it almost certainly returns something of type `IO a` for some type `a`. In this case you *are* doing a daisy-chain of functions in the context of the outside world, so using monads is necessary.

`return` is a function that, in this case, has the type

```
return :: a -> IO a
```

It really should have been called `pure` because it takes a pure value and wraps it up in the monadic context. (When you get to Applicative Functors you will find a version of `return` that is called `pure`).

A rule about monads is that once you are in a monadic context you can't get out; you can carry out pure computations on values within the context, but the results stay in the monadic context. That context is denoted by a type like "IO". So in this case your function type should be

```
vote :: PostId -> Bool -> IO (Maybe (Int, Int))
```

However if you try that you will find that it still doesn't work. The first branch of your `case` is fine, because it returns `Nothing`. But the second branch has a type error because it tries to return `(nuv, nvd)` after an IO action. You've tried to factor out the `return`, but actually you need to `return Nothing` in your first branch and then `return $ Just (nuv, nvd)` at the end of the second.

Incidentally you don't need a new `let` for each value. You can say

```
let
   foo = 1
   bar = 2
return (foo, bar)
```

Comment: I don't buy that Maybe is the simplest monad there is. Arguably Reader is just as simple, but even if you disagree then Identity is clearly simpler.

Comment: Also the `vote` function needs more fixing than you suggest, because it tries to do some IO in the second branch. Instead of `return $ case ...`, it will have to look more like `case p of {Nothing -> return Nothing; Just p -> do ... return (nuv, ndv)}`.